Keyboard is Creating Extra Characters When Typing!
When typing on the keyboard is it random adding characters to text.
When I hit a 0 it will create a 00 double zero.
Hiting the slash creates a 3-
Hel9p! This is driving me nutes. I can7àt figure it out. It does not happen pre6'login so something is loading it.
Yes. I have rebooted. I even wiped and reinstalled the OS!

You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; so we can't provide any OS related clues anyway; however you're describing what reads (to me) like a hardware issue, and have provided no clues as to any testing you've performed that would rule that out.  Why ask here? this is a Ubuntu site, and not a hardware site, and you've only outlined a likely hardware related issue without any specifics to why asking here.

It might be a hardware problem.  Do you have a spare keyboard that you can try?  (Or borrow one from a friend?)
